# Why is my UIView.transition animation code not affecting the display?

Tags: ios, swift, animation, uiview

I'm using a UIView transition in my code like so:

```
@IBOutlet var startup_text: UIImageView!

let transition_text = UIImage(named: "name.png")

UIView.transition(with: self.startup_text, duration: 1.0, options:
    .transitionCrossDissolve,
    animations: {
        self.startup_text.image = transition_text
    },
    completion: nil)
```

The IBOutlet is connected, and "name.png" is displaying without a cross dissolve.

Thank you!

Comment: Where is this call to `UIView.transition`?

Comment: It is within the viewDidLoad() func

Comment: A view isn't visible in `viewDidLoad`. Try `viewDidAppear`.

Comment: Thanks a ton. I need to go bury my head in the swift docs :).

Answer (score 0):

Answer in comments of posted question via @rmaddy